# "Access violation writing location" when trying to read from a file

Tags: c++, access-violation

I am getting this error

> Exception thrown at 0x0FC04AFF (vcruntime140d.dll) in Ergasia.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000020.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Which takes me to this part of my code :

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < width*height * 3; i = i + 3) {

    file.read((char *)cR, 1);
    file.read((char *)cG, 1);
    file.read((char *)cB, 1);

    buffer[i] = cR / 255.0f;
    buffer[i + 1] = cG / 255.0f;
    buffer[i + 2] = cB / 255.0f;
}
```

I tried using try/catch and some other if checks but neither worked. Anyone knows what's causing it?

Comment: The program can't be safely continued after this occours, and you can't catch that exception.

Comment: Even if the exception can be caught, the exception indicates a bug in your program. The correct course of action is ***not*** to bury your head in a pile of sand, and hope everything is ok, but to find and the fix the real bug in your code.

Comment: Try catch will not work in this case since this is not a c++ error, but an operating system error. Os is trying to write or reserve space on a dummy location because you said that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's causing it is that you are trying to write to memory at location 0x20, but that is impossible, because there is never any writable memory located at such a low memory location. You could have figured this out rather easily by reading the error message:

> Access violation writing location 0x00000020

The obvious next question is where you're getting a pointer to memory at the address 0x20, since that is obviously not a valid address. Your code is somewhat incomplete, using variables whose definitions we cannot see, but it looks to me like you are casting character values to `char*`, which is almost certainly incorrect. Presumably, `cR`, `cG`, and `cB` is supposed to be the intensity of the red, green, and blue color channels for an RGB bitmap. They are ***not*** pointers to memory, so you should not be casting them to `char*` as if they were.

I'm assuming that `file.read` is a function that reads a color value from a file, and writes it into the memory location pointed to by its first parameter. If that's true, then you should be passing the ***address*** of the variable to the function, rather than *casting* the value to a pointer. The `&` (address-of) operator is used in C++ to retrieve a pointer to a variable:

```
file.read(&cR, 1);
file.read(&cG, 1);
file.read(&cB, 1);
```

As others have rightfully pointed out in the comments, you should not be catching Access Violation errors. And, in general, you should make sure that an exception is not being caused by a bug in your program before trying to catch and ignore it.

Comment: ahhh I'm so stupid... the char*  cast was correct, i forgot the &

Comment: You should not need a cast…that is probably just masking another bug. What is the prototype of your `file.read` function?

Comment: I am using ifstream if that's what you are asking. Also cR, cG, and cB are unsigned chars